# How can i convert plane text to PDF in Jquery without removing space as right now it is concatenating whole string in one line using JSPDF?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jspdf

I was trying to convert string message which has space and breaks in 'textarea' input html to PDF in Jquery using JSPDF ..but it is removing space and concatenating whole string in one line.But i dont want that ..i want pdf with same string message as in text area.is there any third party JS like jspdf which just convert string to pdf without removing any spaces and breaks. Thnx.

### Code to generate the pdf

```
 var html = '<textarea cols="20" id="textoutput" name="textoutput" 
rows="2" class="">' + $("#text").val() + </textarea>';
doc.fromHTML(html, 15, 15, {'width': 170,'elementHandlers': 
specialElementHandlers
});
doc.save('samplefile.pdf');
```

### Html input data

Hi test,

test test

test value

Regards,
Test

### Generated pdf Output

Hi test,test testtest valueRegards,Test

Comment: [First take a look at the help section about how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hi @RickBronger ,i have modified question ,,do you  have any solution for this or different way to do this task other than JSPDF?Thnx.

Comment: I found many samples where it is working as you want it to work. [here is a complete working sample](https://codepen.io/ianaya89/pen/JoRNyK)

Comment: Thnx ..sample is working fine but there is autopaging and text wrap issues...                                                                                                                  i solved these issue ....see code  in answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
                                                                                                                                                                                                var doc = new jsPDF();
        var splitTitle = doc.splitTextToSize($('#textarea').val(), 270);
        var pageHeight = doc.internal.pageSize.height;
        doc.setFontType("normal");
        doc.setFontSize("11");
        var y = 7;
        for (var i = 0; i < splitTitle.length; i++) {                
            if (y > 280) {
                y = 10;
                doc.addPage();
            }
            doc.text(15, y, splitTitle[i]);
            y = y + 7;
        }
        doc.save('my.pdf');
```